# Putting wamp online prob

Tags: wamp

Alright, so I've downloaded wamp server before an hour. I was trying to put it online and I just couldn't. I'm getting the following exception: "could not execute menu item internal error exception could not perform service action". I was googling it and I found 2 solutions.
1 of them is to change the ports of the skype, and other programs from port 80 to another one.
I don't have any of these programs, so it's should be OK.
The second solution is to change the port of the wamp to 8080 or whatever, I tried this also and it's still not working.(The icon of the wamp is orange).
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please keep the world safer and do not put your server online unless you are aware of the risks, can configure WAMP to be more safer and keep your system up-to-date.

Comment: Do u have IIS installed in your machine ?

Comment: firstable i agree with @Lekensteyn wamp is insecure second where did changed wamp port to 8080 ?

Comment: @elibyy What do you guys mean by saying that it is insecure? Eveyone uses wamp,no? and to your answer: I changed in the httpdf Listen 8080

Comment: @pinaldesai I suppose I don't since I don't know what it is,(is it a program?)

Comment: it's a webserver like apache for microsoft OS

Comment: the wamp system is meant for testing , not for real webserver... when you put it online i can access it if i know your IP what you should do is start all services but leave the server offline so you will be able to access thru 127.0.0.1

Comment: @elibyy That's exactly what I want to do, I entered this IP and I can't connect to it(unavailable).

Comment: you want to load wamp via your wan IP or lan IP ?

Comment: anyways when i had this kind of problem it was a problem that i installed 32-bit instead of 64-bit check it out

Answer (score 0):

I use WampDeveloper Pro, so it's a bit different, but I'll assume that your problem is that Apache will not start.

You'll need to get the specific Apache error message to understand what the problem is.

Open the command line (run cmd.exe), and within type in: `httpd t`.

This will perform a syntax check. If it's okay, then type in: `httpd -k start`.

This will attempt to start Apache, and if unsuccessful, will print out the error.

If the error is something like "can't bind to 0.0.0.0:80, port already in use" (the error will be a bit more clinical than that) then you are right, something else is already taking up port 80.

In which case, type in: `netstat -aon`. Look for the line that says "0.0.0.0:80" and note the PID number. Then get in your Windows Task Manager (ctrl-alt-del), into the Processes Tab, click "Show process from all". Find the process that has the same PID number. This is what you need to shut down or reconfigure to listen on another port.

Answer (score 0):

hey have you tried to put off any othe installed server like IIS for example ?? if you have IIS turned on go to services and stop world wide publishing service and than try restart all wamp services and then put it online it sould work :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly its Apache problem.

I had the same problem. The problem is that the port Apache is trying to use is actually being used by some other application. Either

1. Change the port no. from the file http.conf or httpd.conf from 80 to smething else Listen 8080 change 8080 to something else.
2. check out which application is using the port and shut it down. Check the port status using "cports" aplication or any other that you prefer. Then it will work just fine.